# Certain site is getting redirected to another page

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, internet, isp

My ISP is known for their intrusive behavior.

Let's say `warheat1990.com` is a porn/gambling site with IP address `77.77.77.77` (my ISP will block these site). When I open `warheat1990.com` from my browser (chrome, firefox, IE same result), it will redirect me to ISP internet safety page.

I checked my DNS on ipleak.com to make sure and it shows the correct OpenDNS IP addresses. I even tried to ping `warheat1990.com` and it shows reply from `77.77.77.77` so I'm pretty sure the DNS is doing its job correctly.

I can access the site just fine via IP address (by using `77.77.77.77`), however accessing the site using domain name will always redirect me to ISP safety internet page.

Any idea why?

Comment: Try adding `warheat1990.com` to your Host file.                                    `77.77.77.77    www.warheat1990.com` and see if the same behavior happens. Follow this guide [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

Comment: still no luck..

Comment: A hosts file on windows 7 wont change it immediatly, you have to flush dns first (at least), and remember that some browsers use thier own DNS methods. Disabling the  "DNS Client" service in services will just disable the cache. When piddling with the hosts file having the cache disabled helps.  The hosts file also doesnt get loaded up under certian odd conditions, one of them being the system sees that things like the time changed on the file, where the system then assumes something of that changed, so it then reads it again.

Comment: Do this and see what it says. Open Command Prompt type in this command `nslookup -type=txt which.opendns.com.  208.67.220.220` and see what the ouput is your isp may be even directing your open DNS to their own.

Comment: Are you using your ISP's default DNS? If so, don't. Use Google's public DNS instead.

Comment: Also have a look here [OpenDNS Website still being blocked](https://support.opendns.com/entries/26032674-Open-DNS-doesn-t-work-still-websites-being-blocked) and see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: It is the ISP who is redirecting to another site by means of prohibition of some sites. There is no issue with DNS. sometime Google DNS allows you to visit the site if your system setting changed. But your ISP may overcome this and block the site. So it is fully depends on your ISP. If they are not allowed to view, then you can't see it. Simple...

Comment: Your ISP is blocking the URL warheat1990.com using domain name regex. When ever the content filter encounters this is porn site --> ISP redirects to safety page.